# Использование изображения в SplashScreen как фон (на весь экран)

Tags: java

Доброй ночи. Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне быть.
У меня изображение фона SplashScreen прописано в style:

`<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/ic_bg_splash_screen</item>`. Но приложение на телефон не устанавливается при таком раскладе (я так полагаю проблема в переполнении памяти, потому что при использовании @color/colorPrimary, все устанавливается и работает хорошо). Не подскажете, как можно избежать такую проблему? И правилен ли вообще такой подход к заданию фона у SplashScreen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен путем уменьшения размера фонового изображения вручную.